# React Error: Nothing was returned from render

Tags: reactjs

Note: I already looked through similar questions; the solutions provided do not solve my problem.

I am getting the following error in my React app

> TasksColumn(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually >means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return >null.

Here is the relevant code:

**`TasksColumn.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

const taskData = [
  {
    title: "Preliminary Report",
    course: "Capstone Design",
    type: "Report",
    deadline: "2019-10-04"
  },
  {
    title: "title2",
    course: "course2",
    type: "type2",
    deadline: "date2"
  },
  {
    title: "title3",
    course: "course3",
    type: "type3",
    deadline: "deadline3"
  }
];

const TaskRecord = ({ title, course, type, deadline }) => {
  return (
    <Row class="task-record">
      <Col>
        <div class="task-record-title">
          <h5>{title}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="task-record-course">
          <h6>{course}</h6>
        </div>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <div class="task-record-type">
          <p>{type}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="task-record-deadline">
          <p>{deadline}</p>
        </div>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default class TasksColumn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      mounted: false,
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
      mounted: true
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { tasks } = this.props;
    let mounted = this.state.mounted;

    if (mounted == true) {
      return (
        <Col id="tasks-column">
          {tasks.map((task, i) => (
            <TaskRecord
              key={i}
              title={task.title}
              course={task.course}
              type={task.type}
              deadline={task.deadline}
            />
          ))}
        </Col>
      );
    }
  }
}

render(<TasksColumn tasks={taskData} />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

**`Dashboard.js`**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import TasksColumn from "../../molecules/TasksColumn";

export default function Dashboard(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <TasksColumn />
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

As an end result, I need the `TasksColumns` in `Dashboard.js` to render each `taskData` inside a `TaskRecord`.

Comment: Hi R.Antao, please see my solution below and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `TaskColumn` class, specifically the `render` method:

```js
class TaskColumn extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const mounted = this.state.mounted

    // DON'T DO THIS
    if (mounted == true) {
      return (...)
    }
  }
}
```

According to the `React.js` docs:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree)

Since your `render` function only returns the `JSX` when `mounted` is `true`, essentially you are returning `undefined` when `mounted` is `false`. This happens when your component mounts for the first time (before `componentDidMount` gets triggered) and is wrong as the `render` function has to return any of the following:

- React elements
- Arrays and fragments
- Portals
- String and numbers
- Booleans or null

Have a look here to read more: [reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render](http://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render).

If you don't want to render anything before you meet a certain condition, you should just return `null`:

```js
class TaskColumn extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { tasks } = this.props
    const isLoading = this.state.isLoading

    if (isLoading) {
      return <h1>Loading</h1>
    }
    if (!isLoading && tasks && tasks.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Col>
         {tasks.map(...)}
        </Col>
      )
    }
    // otherwise return null if you don't want to 
    // show anything until data/tasks become available
    return null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `TaskColumn` component, currently you are only returning something when `mounted` is `true`. But mounted isnt set to `true` until your logic in `componentDidMount()`. `componentDidMount()` only is triggered after the first render. You still need to `return` something for the **initial** render when mounted is still `false`:

```
export default class TasksColumn extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
               isLoading: false,
           mounted: false,
           data: []
          };
     }
     componentDidMount() {
          this.setState({
           isLoading: true,
        mounted: true
          });
     }
     render() {
          const { tasks } = this.props;
      let mounted = this.state.mounted;

          if (mounted == true) {
           return ( 
                <Col id="tasks-column">
                 {tasks.map((task, i) => 
                  <TaskRecord 
                       key={i}
                   title={task.title} 
                       course={task.course} 
                   type={task.type}
                   deadline={task.deadline}
                  />
                 )}
             </Col>
           );  
         } else {
            return <div>woof</div>
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Adding the else {return null} (or woof), worked! Thanks Chris.

Comment: @R.Antao you're welcome friend! Please consider marking this as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `taskData` as props to `taskColumn` where you call it, ie in `Dashboard`. This is better practice because this way, the "caller" component controls its children component. Having it set up this way is cleaner and more readable. React is like this all the way - all about modularity and breaking things down and keeping data flows clean. Read here for more: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html.

You shouldn't need

```
render (
    <TasksColumn tasks={taskData}/>, 
    document.querySelector("#root")
)
```

outside a Component, since you now have all these components set up with their
individual render methods.

Other notes:
You probably don't need two state variables for 'mounted' / 'loading' for your use case so far. Just use PropTypes to set defaults (or make required) `taskData`. Example:

```
TasksColumn.propTypes = {
  taskData: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    title: PropTypes.string,
    course: PropTypes.string,
    type: PropTypes.string,
    deadline: PropTypes.string,
  }))
};

TasksColumn.defaultProps = {
  taskData: [
    {
      title: '',
      course: '',
      type: '',
      deadline: '',
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using render name for react DOM which is conflicting with render method.

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

```
ReactDOM.render (
    <TasksColumn tasks={taskData}/>, 
    document.querySelector("#root")
);
```